Prove that $a=0$ if and only if $b=0$ for the cubic $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c=0$ whose roots all have the same absolute value.
Take three real numbers $a, b$ and $c$ such that the roots of equation $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$ have the same absolute value. We need to show that $a=0$ if and only if $b=0$.
I tried taking the roots as $p, p, p$ or $p, -p, p$ and so on and showing with Vieta's formulae how $p=0$ and hence the sum of roots, which in this case, should be $-a$, is equal to zero, so $a=0$. I am looking for a better hint on how to proceed.

The problem given is equivalent to the following situation:

Given $|p|=|q|=|r|$, prove that $p+q+r=0$ if and only if $pq+qr+rp=0$.

($\rightarrow$) As there are only three variables, the number of positive and negative numbers must differ by an odd number. Hence if $p+q+r=0$, this implies that $p=q=r=0$.
($\leftarrow$) Again, the number of positive terms and negative terms in $pq, qr, rp$ must differ by an odd number(You can list them all, i.e when all are positive, when only one is positive,...) Hence $p=q=r=0$.
Hence we are done. This proof is essentially same as what you thought, but it is more concise.

I think this is a great logical approach to it, but could you provide some more context about how (in the forward direction) you concluded about the number of positive and negative numbers differing by an odd number? Also, how did that imply $p=q=r=0$. Would be of some great help. Thanks!

For the $\leftarrow$ direction @Gwen has given a great explanation, and for the $\rightarrow$ direction, let $m$ be the number of positive numbers among $p, q, r$, and let $n$ be the number of negative numbers among $p, q, r$. Unless one of them(hence all of them are) is zero, $m+n=3$, so that the difference of $m, n$ is also odd.

I'm proving what @Joshua Woo had written. I think you'll be able to continue from there.
$$pq+qr+rp=0$$ then
$$2pq+2qr+2rp=0$$ This means that
$$(p+q+r)^2=p^2+q^2+r^2+2pq+2qr+2rp=p^2+q^2+r^2$$
Hence $(p+q+r)$ can only be equal to zero if $p=0,q=0,r=0$ and $2pq+2qr+2pr=0$, given that $p,q,r$ are real
